# installing pandas in python 2.7, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, ubuntu-12.04

when i initially ran

```
  $ pip install pandas
```

it gave me an error that i don't have permissions.
then when i tried

```
  $ sudo pip install pandas
```

it gave me this -

```
  fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

After some search, i came across this command

```
  $ sudo pip install -U pandas
```

after a very, very verbose output, it gave the same error but this time it prompted me that i might need/want to install python-dev & python-setuptools
after installing python-dev, pip install pandas worked fine and without a hitch!

So, my question is, does anyone know why this problem occurred?! Has this occurred before?! 
and what does the -U in $ pip install -U ... stand for?! it isn't mentioned in the help page for pip, i checked!

Also, i know that there's a log file for at /home/user/.pip/pip.log but instead of appending error messages to the log file, it gets rewritten each time there's pip runs into a problem.

Is there anyway to fix this?! 
Also, can i make pip log every install as well and not just the ones that went wrong! 
instead of having to do

```
  $ pip install ... >> LOG_FILE
```

everytime!

EDIT 1 : turns out i didn't do enough research, i found that Python.h isn't necessarily installed by default though i have them installed.

But i'd still like to know what the -U stands for and how to keep a log file in pip.

Comment: Why is this off-topic? It's about installing programming tools and libraries.

Comment: This is of interest to programmers first and foremost (not sysadmins).  Those who closed this question should think  a moment "where else would this go"  and "well aren't python programmers interested in this?"

Comment: I don't get why it's off-topic either. The real problem is it's asking at least 3-4 different questions at once, so closing as "too broad" or an aggressive edit would be more appropriate.

Comment: btw I followed the answer below "python-dev package is necessary" - and now i'm set. I'm happy this question is here.

Answer (score 2):

You always need the `python-dev` package to compile Python C extensions such as the ones in Pandas. When you install Python from source, they're installed along, but not with the Ubuntu package.

From `pip install --help`:

```
-U, --upgrade         Upgrade all packages to the newest available version
```

Comment: yeah, i just read that the python-dev package is necessary. 
i'm just going through pip install --help right now but any comments on how to keep the log file from being rewritten?!

Comment: @rahul.poruri: Have you tried `pip --log`?

Comment: /home/user/.pip/pip.log is the default pip log file and when i link it using pip ... --log = /home/user/.pip/pip.log, it seems to work i.e the pip file isn't being re-written but it's being appended to. In the case when pip fails, the log file is being rewritten.